# Как правильно подключить Google Map к проекту Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, google-maps

У меня вопрос по подключению Google Map к проекту Android.
В целом, я хочу добиться того, чтобы в моем фрагменте в активности отображалась карта, но увы, я не могу понять, что я сделал не так. Выполнял подключение по инструкции представленной в официальной документации к API.

Вот мои листинги кода:

**Манифест**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hfad.mapsstudy">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyC****************************eKI"/>
</application>
```

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.hfad.mapsstudy"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
}
```

**content_main**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.hfad.mapsstudy.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity**:

```
package com.hfad.mapsstudy;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action",     Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
            .title("Marker"));
}
}
```

В Gradle Console пишет ошибку:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program    Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --   debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: Попробуйте в настройках указать использование 7 явы вместо 8. Т.е. jdk1.7 вместо jdk1.8

Comment: Изменил версию jdk на 1.7.
Ошибка та же.

Comment: Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь [с мнением сообщества](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/93/177345) о приветствиях и прочих не относящихся непосредственно к вопросу отступлениях

Comment: Приведите в вопросе ссылку на мануал, по коему делаете

Comment: **Первый источник**: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/306-urok-139-google-maps-sozdanie-i-nastrojka-proekta-karta-kamera-sobytija.html



**Второй источник**: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при подключении play-service вы практически гарантировано обрекаете себя на 64к+ методов в вашем приложении. Чтобы собрать такой проект нужно дополнительно включить multiDex

[Как это сделать сказано тут (ссылка на док. google)](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

А вообще чтобы избежать такой проблемы, не подключайте весь пакет play-service а используйте только

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2
```

Так же дам ссылку на страницу google по подключаемым библиотекам

[google documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)